# Does a mix of analyzers alter the results' score in Lucene?

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, analyzer

I am using **version 4.4** of Apache Lucene.

In a first version of my system, I index the collection of documents with a `SpanishAnalyzer` into five different fields.

In the current version, I have realized that the `SpanishAnalyzer` stemms me names and surnames, and Martinez and Martin are the same for the system. Thus, I am using a `PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper` in order to maintain the `SpanishAnalyzer`  as the default analyzer, and index the names with another one, i.e. `StopAnalyzer`.

This works, and the names and surnames are not stemmed. The searcher has the same `PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper` analyzer.

However, the score computing differs from the first version. It makes strange things (yes, I havn't a better explanation). It seems that mixing analyzers gives more score to some field (when each one has a `boost` 1). I have also experimented something similar when mixing BooleanQueries.
 `(BooleanQuery(BooleanQuery(A or B) or C))`

Does anyone know if these mixes (of analyzers or BooleanQueries) should alter the score?

**Version 1** Names stemmed

```
Analyzer analyzer = new SpanishAnalyzer(LUCENE_VERSION);
IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(LUCENE_VERSION, analyzer);
```

[**Scores**](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AhSXcxdlPTbTiENjme6RfPG3ACK2)

**Version 2** Names not stemmed

```
Map<String,Analyzer> specificAnalyzers = new HashMap<String,Analyzer>();
/* Author field has a stop analyzer so that names and surnames
 * are not stemmed, and Martinez is not the same as Martin. */
specificAnalyzers.put(AUTHOR_FIELD, new StopAnalyzer(LUCENE_VERSION));
PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper analyzer = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(
    new SpanishAnalyzer(LUCENE_VERSION), specificAnalyzers);
IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(LUCENE_VERSION, analyzer);
```

[**Scores**](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AhSXcxdlPTbTiEI8F2eLOK2Pk6pj)

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Changing to an unstemmed analyzer could certainly change scores though. If Martin and Martinez were both being stemmer to "martin", then removing stemming will result in each of those terms having less matching instances in the index, thus boosting their idf score. Could be other impacts. Are you seeing any particular problems with the scores you are getting?

Comment: @femtoRgon I have added the top 5 results. As you can see, they differ a lot by just adding the specific author analyzer (I have added some boosts to the fields, but they are the same in both versions). What you say is true, but I meant that the score is affected in all the fields (as you can see in the edit).